# Hot deploy DMN file on springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dmn

I am new with DMN.
I have started from the [kogito-example from github](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples)

I have forked it [here](https://github.com/jcast85/kogito-examples) just to have a simplified situation in order to have the Springboot example only.

I am using apache-maven-3.8.8.

I have built and run the Springboot application and then I was able to invoke the REST API

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Driver":{"Points":2},"Violation":{"Type":"speed","Actual Speed":120,"Speed Limit":100}}' http://localhost:8080/Traffic%20Violation
```

But this is a static situation. I mean the dmn file is "deployed" ad startup time.

I would like to have no dmn file at startup time and when the app is running, I would like the dmn is "deployed" at run time.
In detail before the deploy the REST call shouldn't work and after the hot deploy it should.

I really don't know what is the way to go. Any idea?